# R - Having trouble making US heatmap of states

Tags: r

I am trying to make a US state heatmap of the Tidy Tuesday data this week. I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work and I am thinking this should only take a few lines of code.

- Is USMAP the best way to do mapping like this in R?
- Is there a ggplot way to do this instead of using the usmap package?
- What am I doing wrong in my example?

  ```
  library(usmap)
  library(tidyverse)

  nurses <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2021/2021-10-05/nurses.csv')

  plot_data <- nurses %>% 
  filter(Year == 2020) %>% 
  select(State, `Total Employed RN`) %>% 
  rename("Total_Employed" = 2)

  # Works with no data
  plot_usmap()

  # Does not work with data ??
  plot_usmap(data = plot_data,
           values = Total_Employed,
           color = "blue") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "white",
                        high = "blue")

  # The column is real and I can access it
  plot_data %>% 
  mutate(test_column = (1 + Total_Employed))

  # Trying to emulate an example from : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/usmap/vignettes/mapping.html
  statepop <- statepop %>% 
  rename(State = 3)

  merged_df <- left_join(plot_data, statepop, by = "State") %>% 
  select(fips, abbr, Total_Employed, State)
  merged_df

  # Still does not work even though data is in the same format
  plot_usmap(data = merged_df,
           values = Total_Employed,
           color = "blue") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "white",
                        high = "blue")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Various answers in this thread: https://twitter.com/Indescribled/status/1445234775858368514

My preferred one - https://twitter.com/ivelasq3/status/1445242672021606401